# Reduce size of a large JPEG without changing resolution

Tags: java, android

I have a JPEG from my camera that is 3264x1952.  This file is about 1.7 megabytes.

I'm wondering is there anyway to compress this image to a smaller file size **without** changing the resolution. i.e. I want my resultant image to also be 3264x1952.

I cannot even open this JPEG as a bitmap without using the inSampleSize option to scale down the image.

Anyone know what my options are? Is there any way to reduce color bit depth/increase compression/reduce quality?

edit:
I'm specifically looking for a solution for Android. Main problem being I can't open the full res JPEG without hitting a OOM error, so I don't know how to proceed.

Ideally I'd like to do:

```
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, out);
```

But the application will crash when I do:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programatically Reducing JPEG file size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6830478/programatically-reducing-jpeg-file-size)

Comment: reduce your image quality then..

Comment: @Segi I can't reduce my image quality because I can't open the file as a bitmap in the first place...

Comment: then put your code for that..

Comment: @Segi Added some code.

Comment: Maybe this helps, there is a section about loading a scaled down version of an IMage into mem: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: have you got path or that image.?

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `BitmapFactory.decodeFile` method that takes as second paramter a `BitmapFactory.Options` object and use `inSampleSize` to scale the image. For instance an `inSampleSize = 2` will produce an output image of `width/2` and `height/2,` . Just remember that your bitmap need always `width x heigth x 4` bytes of memory

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use [BitmapFactory.decodeStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeStream%28java.io.InputStream,%20android.graphics.Rect,%20android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options%29), taking in a stream from the JPEG file. You can modify the density before the bitmap is returned.

Answer (score 0):

You need to scale down your image.

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html.

Use appropriate `Bitmap.decode` method and scale down the image.

[Bitmap.decode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeByteArray%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options%29)

Example :

Call the method with the required parameters.

```
public static Bitmap decodeFile(File f,int WIDTH,int HIGHT){
 try {
     //Decode image size
     BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
     o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
     BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

     //The new size we want to scale to
     final int REQUIRED_WIDTH=WIDTH;
     final int REQUIRED_HIGHT=HIGHT;
     //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
     int scale=1;
     while(o.outWidth/scale/2>=REQUIRED_WIDTH && o.outHeight/scale/2>=REQUIRED_HIGHT)
         scale*=2;

     //Decode with inSampleSize
     BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
     o2.inSampleSize=scale;
     return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
 } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
 return null;
}
```